# python - how to reduce number of wql calls either by mapping classes or attributes?

Tags: python, wmi, wmi-query

Here is where im stuck with. I have many wmi classes to query a remote host(Hyper-v) and VM's inside. I can call them in serial query but it takes too much time getting output. I want to have minimum number of query calls and get the attributes specified.

For example : While getting the CPU information, in class Win32_Processor, i want Description,NumberOfCores,LoadPercentage and count of sockets (i.e, count of SocketDesignation) and sometimes for CPU information only i will use 2 classes (as some attributes i want will not be available in the single class)

similarly, while getting Memory information, in class Win32_ComputerSystem, i want TotalPhysicalMemory and memory usage. And the list goes on.

My question is, is there a way i can map these calls either by using classes or attributes to minimize the number of calls in python?

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you.